# How to get rid of Fatal error encountered during command execution. in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Here Im trying to insert status value to database on button click. Following is the code:

```
protected void Button7_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    String query = @"insert into event (Status) values (@sender.ToString()) where time='" + Time + "'";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sender.ToString()", sender.ToString());
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(HttpUnhandledException ex){}
    conn.Close();
}
```

In `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, it gives fatal error execution. Kindly tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: **What** exception do you get? Don't make us guess. (and yes, I can see why you're getting an error, this is just general advice for the future)

Comment: @J.Steen although most probably could :)

Comment: You need update statement it looks like

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yeah you are right. So , I changed my query to this :  String query = @"update event set Status = '"+ s +" 'where time='" + Time + "'";      but it is not being updated at the back end (MYSQL database)

Comment: @puffles Debug it and see what values are being passed

Answer (score 0):

Insert statement cannot have a where clause. Remove the where clause from the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
String query = @"insert into event (Status) values (@sender.ToString()) where time='" + Time + "'";
```

@sender.Tostring() is Incorrect syntax that's why you get fetal error during command execution.

Always remember that fetal error occurred during command execution only because of incorrect parameters value name.

so correct the parameter value to avoid fetal errors during command execution.

In your code sender is button7 that you have clicked.
so to retrieve the sender value you need to first type cast the sender like

```
string text = ((Button)sender).Text;
```

then the final code would be like

```
protected void Button7_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    string text = ((Button)sender).Text; 
    String query = @"insert into event (Status) values (@param) where time='" + Time + "'";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", text);
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(HttpUnhandledException ex){}
    conn.Close();
}
```

OR

```
protected void Button7_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{ 
        String query = @"insert into event (Status) values (@param) where time='" + Time + "'";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", ((Button)sender).Text);
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(HttpUnhandledException ex){}
        conn.Close();
    }
```